# Stuck with ethernet

Tags: router, ethernet, bridge

I have an old router that I was wondering if it would be possible to use it as a bridge as such to extend Ethernet For example Main router - Ethernet - Router 2 - Ethernet - device!

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think that would depend on whether it's a cable router or a dsl router. If it's a cable router probably yes if it's dsl probably not.

Comment: if you have multiple lan ports on the old router, then you can always just use it as a switch. just don't use the wan interface.

Answer (score 0):

If both routers are functioning correctly, you should definitely be able to do that. Here are some options you can try

Setup 1 -- Internet Service provider -- (WAN)Router1(LAN)--- (WAN)Router2(LAN)--- 
Assuming both are cable. In this case, keep in mind you might end up having 2 subnets, that of each router.

Setup 2 -- Internet Service provider -- (WAN) Route1 (LAN) --- (LAN)Router2(LAN)---
In this case, you will "lose" one port of the router2 but depending on how old the router is, it should have 'auto sensing' capability that will let your devices connected to Router2 be on the same subnet as that of router1. If you have a DSL router, this might be your only choice.

If your router supports DD-WRT, you could connect a cable to the WAN port of router 2 and still get it to behave like a LAN port/switch.

Comment: If you go with Setup 2, be sure to turn off DHCP on Router2 as you only want one DHCP server per LAN.